# ASP.NET Core Stream/load large video files to front without having memory overflows or temp files in

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, video-streaming

Cannot load video files in front with range processing in ASP.NET Core. Instead, it is reading the whole file (which is nearly 1 GB) into memory then sends it back to the browser. Code that I tried:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoadVideo(string fileName)
    {
        var link = $"http://192.168.20.12/videos/{fileName}";

        HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(link);
        HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse) fileReq.GetResponse();
        if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
            fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;
        var stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();


        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
        Response.Headers.Add("Accept-Range", "bytes");
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());

        return new FileStreamResult(stream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4"))
        {
            EnableRangeProcessing = true,
        };
    }
```

Comment: Found an answer ?